# Create a ListItem method as array of strings c#

Tags: c#

I am having difficulties in the below question

How do I create the below `ListItem` method to return a array of `string`s?

```
public static List<ListItem> GetSelectedListItems(CheckBoxList _ddl)
{
    List<ListItem> GetData = new List<ListItem>();

    foreach (ListItem item in _ddl.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected) GetData.Add(item);
    }

    return GetData;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
public static string[] GetSelectedListItems(CheckBoxList _ddl)
     {
     List<string> GetData = new List<string>();

     foreach (ListItem item in _ddl.Items)
     {
        if (item.Selected) GetData.Add(item.Text);
     }

     return GetData.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Enumerable.Cast` because [`CheckBoxList.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't a generic collection:

```
return _ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
```

If you want to return  `string[]` of all selected items:

```
return _ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Text).ToArray();
```